# VS2010 Build number - easy way to generate it and display it in application

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, build-process

C# / VS2010

What is the easiest way to obtain a build number? I have noticed that when I PUBLISH a project, there is this publish version. Is there an equivalent to do something similar when just building - and not publishing.

Goal: I want to display an automatically updated version / build number in the application, so I need be able to fetch it at runtime - and of course somehow generate it.

Of course, I could write a little batch file doing things (pre-build). But isn't there something already available...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to make Build Number in VS 2010 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395241.aspx

Also Build Version Add-In for Visual Studio http://autobuildversion.codeplex.com/

Comment: Will try the Add-In, I do not use Team Foundation. I'll be back once I have some experience with the AddIn. Thanks so far,

Comment: The Add-In is nice, only minor issues. This is it for my scenario, single developer and no source code system. I understand the approach will fail if you need consistent versions with > 1 developers. In this case the source control approach comes into picture. Thanks to all who have supported me.

Comment: Funny side effect though, since the assembly always gets a new version number, also the user's application settings go to a different directory (which is equivalent always having default settings)

Answer (score 1):

use the version-number from your source-control-system. you can use a build task to get that number from the source-control and insert into the appropriate files.

Comment: Yep, that's what I would do, but for smaller single developer projects I do not use source control - I should have outlined this situation. Thanks anyway.

Comment: if you want to deploy it somewhere (and thats what i think you will do, otherwise there is no need for the buildnumber), you should always use source control. :)